# Error in MySQL syntax when adding object to objectcontext

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I seem to have trouble adding objects to tables that have a 'n to n' relationship.

Tables are defined as follows:

**Table A**

- ID (PRIMARY)
- ...
- ...
- ...

**Table B**

- ID (PRIMARY)
- ...
- ...
- ...

**Table C**

- TableA_ID (index)
- TableB_ID (index)

So basically Table C links Table A and B, by their IDs. Using the entity framework we now have an object TableA containing an Entity Collection of TableB entities.

However when I add an existing object of type TableB to the TableA.TableBs entity collection property, I receive an exception:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT\n      `TableC`.`TableA`, \n    ' at line 1

It seems that I'm trying to do a very normal / common thing, however I've not been successful getting this to work.

C# code:

```
var database = new DatabaseEntities();
var tableAObject = database.SingleOrDefault(e => e.ID == 1);
var tableBObject = database.SingleOrDefault(e => e.ID == 1);

tableA.TableBEntities.Add(tableBObject);
database.SaveChanges();
```

Apparently I'm doing something wrong, so my question is, how should I add an object to Table C?

Comment: _You have an error in your MySQL syntax at_ Why don't you show the only clue?

Comment: Gert: I've added MySQL error in the question. If there's a way to get the query itself from the linq-to-sql statement, I'm happy to include that in my original post as well, thanks for commenting!

Comment: This is the way to handle many to many relationships. One thing: make sure `tableA.TableBEntities` is loaded before adding item. Which line throws the exception? It looks like a read action.

Comment: tableA.TableBEntities is loaded, it contains all the entries that are  available in the database. The line that throws the exception is database.SaveChanges();